# How can I get a modified value from a TextArea with Tinymce in TWebBrowser (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, element, twebbrowser

In my Delphi application, I have a TWebDocument that loads a document with a TextArea.

Here is the document content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <script src="file://c:/projects/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id="texto">TEXT HERE</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

I can get the text in the textarea with the following code:

```
Element := (wb1.Document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementById('texto');
Edit1.Text := Element.Value;
```

But how about if the user modifies the text in the textarea at runtime? How can I get the modified value?

*Edit: It was because of tinyMCE script. So the real question is how to get the value from a TextArea in TWebBrowser if tinyMCE is active.*

Comment: Er, why do you think that the code in the question doesn't read the current value of the text?

Comment: Because I tested it... I get the outdated text with this code.

Comment: Ok... just an update: if I remove the tinymce script, then I get the current value. But I need the tinymce. Any idea?

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/tinymce//tinymce) the tinymce you mean?

Comment: Yes, actually I used v4.9.5, because I got problems to get the latest version working with TWebBrowser.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, answering my own question:
I changed the tinymce.init to:

```
  tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea',
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        })
    }
  });
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question asked. The question asked has no details of tinymce.

Comment: Well, tinymce is in the code, in the question. If you add this code to the code in the question, you have a solution.